# Java - Get values over a json iteration

Tags: java, arrays, json, httpresponse

What I'm trying to do here is iterate inside a Json Object obtained from an API Call in order to search a value related from a Key. However I'm failing in obtaining the tuples from every iteration. From the following code:

```
public void findResponseValue(String param, String inputValue){

    ArrayList<String> jsonArray = response.getBody().jsonPath().get("");
    Iterator<String> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
        iterator.next();

    }
```

I receive the following error

java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.HashMap and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

It correctly iterates over the arrayList, but it fails trying to take a value from it.

---

Response Body example

```
[
{
    "creationDate": "2017-05-29T07:45:43Z",
    "createdBy": "YYY.YYY",
    "lastUpdate": "2018-09-26T10:10:12Z",
    "updatedBy": "XXX.XXX",
    "id": 22,
    "partner": "ALS",
    "countries": [

    ],
    "countriesCodes": "NL",
    "salesChannels": [
        {
            "code": "Integrated"
        }
    ],
    "touchPoints": [

    ],
    "serviceEntity": "AWPNL",
    "flag": false,
    "activated": true,
    "type": "dcx"
},
{
    "creationDate": "2017-06-01T13:22:29Z",
    "createdBy": "YYY.YYY",
    "lastUpdate": "2017-11-30T12:24:36Z",
    "updatedBy": "MMM.T.NNN",
    "id": 39,
    "partner": "ALS",
    "countries": [

    ],
    "countriesCodes": "ES",
    "salesChannels": [
        {
            "code": "Integrated"
        }
    ],
    "touchPoints": [

    ],
    "serviceEntity": "AWPES",
    "flag": false,
    "activated": true,
    "type": "dcx"
}
]
```

Comment: Well the error seems clear to me, your list consists of HashMap objects, not String objects.

Comment: Can you give an example of response body?

Comment: @StephanHogenboom I added the response body, thanks

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson, I already tried declaring this       HashMap<String, List<String>> jsonHashMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        
        ...

        jsonHashMap = iterator.next();

        Error:(322, 40) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response body should be as below:

```
{"data":[
{
    "creationDate": "2017-05-29T07:45:43Z",
    "createdBy": "YYY.YYY",
    "lastUpdate": "2018-09-26T10:10:12Z",
    "updatedBy": "XXX.XXX",
    "id": 22,
    "partner": "ALS",
    "countries": [

    ],
    "countriesCodes": "NL",
    "salesChannels": [
        {
            "code": "Integrated"
        }
    ],
    "touchPoints": [

    ],
    "serviceEntity": "AWPNL",
    "flag": false,
    "activated": true,
    "type": "dcx"
},
{
    "creationDate": "2017-06-01T13:22:29Z",
    "createdBy": "YYY.YYY",
    "lastUpdate": "2017-11-30T12:24:36Z",
    "updatedBy": "MMM.T.NNN",
    "id": 39,
    "partner": "ALS",
    "countries": [

    ],
    "countriesCodes": "ES",
    "salesChannels": [
        {
            "code": "Integrated"
        }
    ],
    "touchPoints": [

    ],
    "serviceEntity": "AWPES",
    "flag": false,
    "activated": true,
    "type": "dcx"
}
]}
```

This is a method I used (Gson parser API used).
In for loop you can compare your key or value.

```
    public static void findResponseValue(String param, String inputValue){

         JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(jsonResponseBody).getAsJsonObject();
         JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get("data");
         JsonArray jsonArray = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();

         for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i+". Array element Content:"+jsonArray.get(i));

            JsonObject jsonObj = jsonArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

            System.out.println("\t creationDate:"+jsonObj.get("creationDate")+" partner:"+jsonObj.get("partner"));

         }       
    }
```